# Joomla exception "throw new DebugBarException("Session must be started before using stack data in the debug bar");"

Tags: joomla-4.x, restful-api

I have updated my website to Joomla 4.13 and using Postman to get data via Joomla 4 webservices.
I have turned on the Debug.
Now I'm getting a response to the Postman "Session must be started before using stack data in the debug bar" and it turns out /libraries/vendor/maximebf/debugbar/src/DebugBar/DebugBar.php (line 447) throw new DebugBarException("Session must be started before using stack data in the debug bar"); is executing.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: You should report this issue to the developers.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/37784 !